# Cassandra cluster it taking lot of time When I add new node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've 5 node Cass cluster and each one currently owning 1 TB of data. When I tried adding another node, it almost took 15+ Hours to bring to 'UN'  State.

Is there a way to make it fast?

Cassandra version: 3.0.13 
Environment : AWS , m4.2xlarge machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 TB is a lot of data per node. Since you have a 5 node cluster and you're adding a new node that node will take 0,833 TB data that has to be streamed from all nodes. That is the equivalent of 6,67 Tbit, or 6990507 Mbit. Cassandra has a default value for stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec of 200.  6990507÷200 = 34952,535 seconds = 9,7 hours to transfer all data. Since you're probably running other traffic at the same time etc. this could very well take 15 hours.

Solution: Change the stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec on all nodes to a higher value.

Note: Don't forget to run [nodetool cleanup](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCleanup.html) after the node has joined the cluster.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Highly appreciate your response.  Will change those parameter next time when I add new nodes to cluster.

Comment: @Avis Cool. If you consider the question closed you should mark my answer as accepted so that others will know it was helpful.

Comment: Hey Simon, what is is the recommended way of running nodetool cleanup? Is it okay run in parallel or should it also be done node by node ?

Comment: @Avis I would recomend running nodetool cleanup sequentially as it can have a high performance impact depending on how much data needs to be cleaned up. Number of compactions will go up for that node temporarily and will use more cpu / io. If you feel confident that the temporary performance impact isn't an issue for you then you can run cleanup in parallel.