# Adding a new node to cassandra db cluster(that currently has only one node) and over 500GB of Data

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra instance running in production in a project where I have connected hundreds of thousands of sensors to dump data to the cassandra server using c# cassandradriver.

The Server has a 2 TB SSD.

I am not experiencing any performance issues as of Right now, but I plan to add more sensors,
I have only one KeySpace and only one Table in that KeySpace. The structure of the Table is as follows

```
    CREATE TABLE xxxxkeyspace.sensorreadings (
    signalid int,
    monthyear int,
    fromtime bigint,
    totime bigint,
    avg decimal,
    insertdate bigint,
    max decimal,
    min decimal,
    readings text,
    PRIMARY KEY (( signalid, monthyear ), fromtime, totime)
    ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND comment = ''
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
AND caching = {
    'keys' : 'ALL',
    'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'
}
AND compression = {
    'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64,
'class' : 'LZ4Compressor',
'crc_check_chance' : 1.0,
'enabled' : true
}
AND compaction = {
'bucket_high' : 1.5,
'bucket_low' : 0.5,
'class' : 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',
'enabled' : true,
'max_threshold' : 32,
'min_sstable_size' : 50,
'min_threshold' : 4,
'tombstone_compaction_interval' : 86400,
'tombstone_threshold' : 0.2,
'unchecked_tombstone_compaction' : false
};
```

when i run the nodetool status it says that the keyspace has occupied more than 550GB of data on the SSD.

Will there be any issues during production If I add more nodes to the cluster during run-time. Note I can not tolerate a downtime greater than an hour.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176015/1516699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new node without any downtime, once a new node is added in existing ring, range-movement starts, once all data corresponding to acquired tokens are replicated on new node bootstrap process is completed. After bootstrap process finish for new node,  all responsible write request are forwarded to this node as per its tokens.
Now only thing remains is cleanup the data from old nodes for tokens which have been moved to new node, this could be done anytime later using nodetool cleanup command.